# How to add widgets to title bar using tkinter?

Tags: python, linux, macos, tkinter

I am currently learning python and tkinter.

I was wondering how to add a button to the title bar in the "mac osx style". I found a simple picture example:

[image: screenshot showing app written in python using tkinter]

The screenshot shows an app written in python using tkinter.

Can it be available for linux systems ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That application uses an open source extension. See http://opensource.codebykevin.com/native.html

Comment: Oh thanks. Unfortunately it appears I can't install the two toolbars suggested with my actual Xcode ..
Can I make this for Linux system ?

Comment: No, this is an OSX-specific extension.  You can create traditional toolbars, but tkinter won't let you write on top of the window borders. Of course, you could use the `overrideredirect` method and draw all of your own window borders if it's that important to you, in which case you can do anything you want.